# Position fixed with flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, css-position

I am having a bit of an issue understanding the behaviour of flexbox with position fixed divs.

I am trying to get my nav to stick to the bottom but retain the flex styling I have used.

Basically the icons need to be evenly spaced along a row with a bit of margin to pull in the left and right.

This works absolutely fine but as soon as apply position fixed, bottom 0 the icons get squashed together on the bottom left of the screen can someone please explain.

```
const FooterNav = () => { 
 return (
    <div className="FooterNave__div">
      <HomeIcon />
      <SearchOutlinedIcon />
      <LocalHospitalOutlinedIcon />
      <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
      <PersonOutlineOutlinedIcon />
    </div> 
 );
};
<footer className="app__footer">
        <FooterNav />
      </footer>

.app__footer {  
    margin: 0 4vw;
}

.FooterNave__div {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items

Comment: have you tried setting the width explicitly and you also need to set "left"

Comment: @FaisalRashid thanks that sorted it. Left didn't changed anything but setting the with width fixed things for me.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Also thanks to you for the explanation of what was causing the issue. Really helpful.